# android string array - counting number of items

Tags: android, arrays, string, checkbox

I am working on quiz app of which user can select 4 types of question difficulties. The questions and answers are stored in string.xml as string arrays.

If all the checkboxes are ticked, the respective string arrays would be stored to ArrayList NUM_ALL_QuestionNames for later quiz retrieval as the questions inside will be further mixed and shuffled.

Full coding as follows:

```
public class Num_index extends Activity 
{
       String[] NUM_SIM_QuestionNames;
       String[] NUM_MED_QuestionNames;
       String[] NUM_DIF_QuestionNames;
       String[] NUM_EXP_QuestionNames;
       String[] NUM_SIM_AnswerNames;
       String[] NUM_MED_AnswerNames;
       String[] NUM_DIF_AnswerNames;
       String[] NUM_EXP_AnswerNames;

       private List<String> NUM_ALL_QuestionNames;  // for quiz
       private List<String> NUM_ALL_AnswerNames;    // for quiz

       private int QuestionImport;         
       private TextView CheckTextView; 
       private TextView AlertTextView;     

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
          setContentView(R.layout.main_num_index); 

          Button ButtonStart= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
          ButtonStart.setOnClickListener(startButtonListener);


          CheckTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checktextView); 
          AlertTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alerttextView);            
          AlertTextView.setText("Start: No alert");

          NUM_SIM_QuestionNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Num_Q_Simple_List);
          NUM_MED_QuestionNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Num_Q_Medium_List);
          NUM_DIF_QuestionNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Num_Q_Diff_List);
          NUM_EXP_QuestionNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Num_Q_Expert_List);           
          NUM_SIM_AnswerNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Num_A_Simple_List);
          NUM_MED_AnswerNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Num_A_Medium_List);
          NUM_DIF_AnswerNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Num_A_Diff_List);
          NUM_EXP_AnswerNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Num_A_Expert_List);

          NUM_ALL_QuestionNames = new ArrayList<String>();
          NUM_ALL_AnswerNames = new ArrayList<String>();
          NUM_ALL_QuestionNames.clear();
          NUM_ALL_AnswerNames.clear();                                
       };

       private OnClickListener startButtonListener = new OnClickListener() 
       {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
              CheckBox CheckSim = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
              CheckBox CheckMed = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
              CheckBox CheckDif = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
              CheckBox CheckExp = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);    

              if (CheckSim.isChecked()) 
              {
                  QuestionImport= 0;                  
                  QuestionImport = NUM_SIM_QuestionNames.length;
                  int i =0;
                  while (i<QuestionImport)
                  {
                      String Q_toimport = NUM_SIM_QuestionNames[i];
                      String A_toimport = NUM_SIM_AnswerNames[i];                                                       

                      NUM_ALL_QuestionNames.add(Q_toimport);
                      NUM_ALL_AnswerNames.add(A_toimport);                    
                      ++i;                    
                  }           
              };    

// same for other checkbox, not shown here for simplicity //   


              if ((!CheckSim.isChecked()) && (!CheckMed.isChecked()) && (!CheckDif.isChecked()) && (!CheckExp.isChecked()))  
              {
                  int k = 0;
                  if (NUM_ALL_QuestionNames.size() >0) {k= NUM_ALL_QuestionNames.size();}
                  CheckTextView.setText(k);
                  AlertTextView.setText("Please select at least one choice!");
              }

              if ((CheckSim.isChecked()) || (CheckMed.isChecked()) || (CheckDif.isChecked()) || (CheckExp.isChecked()))  
              {
                  int k = 0;
                  if (NUM_ALL_QuestionNames.size() >0) {k= NUM_ALL_QuestionNames.size();}
                  CheckTextView.setText(k);
                  AlertTextView.setText("Have Selection!");
              }                           
          } 
       };
```

Logcat:

```
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:260)
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3680)
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at com.pearappx.iq_3.Num_index$1.onClick(Num_index.java:188)
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
11-17 21:55:41.510: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### Question:

When executing the app, error occurs at line 188, which is the line for
    CheckTextView.setText(k);

I would just like to see whether the NUM_ALL_QuestionNames has imported all the strings, i.e. if each of the arrays has 8 values, the CheckTextView will show 32 if all the 4 levels are ticked, and showing 24 if 3 are ticked and so on.

However to solve for the line 188 problem? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting this error too when trying to pass an `int` to the `setText()' function.

Try converting `k` to a String before passing it to `setText()`

Comment: Thanks it works!! (All the answers point towards this solution, I would like to thank you all and ticks all but unable to tick all...) Matt Swanson answers the earlist~ thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You defined k as an int. You can pass String to setText. Use:

```
CheckTextView.setText(String.valueOf(k));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `CheckTextView.setText(k);` you're invoking the method that sets a Resource ID. Instead, you want to pass in a string representing the integer value. Try `.setText("" + k)`.

Comment: It works! many thanks for your prompt help with detailed explanations!